# Merge A nested Query with another result in SQLite

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I have two sets of queries:

```sql
SELECT 
  t.series_name, 
  ti.num_views_per_telecast 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      ti.telecast_id, 
      ti.network_id, 
      count(*) as num_views_per_telecast 
    FROM 
      tunein AS ti 
      INNER JOIN affiliates AS a ON ti.network_id = a.network_id 
    WHERE 
      ti.dvr_time_shift = 'L+SD' 
      and a.network_name = 'ABC' 
    group by 
      ti.telecast_id, 
      ti.network_id
  ) ti 
  inner join telecast AS t On t.telecast_id = ti.telecast_id 
ORDER BY 
  ti.num_views_per_telecast DESC
```

And

```sql
select 
  distinct * 
from 
  telecast 
where 
  episode_name = 'friday night dinner' 
  and series_name = 'A Million Little Things' 
  and date(program_start_local) = '2018-10-17'
```

I want to be able to combine the two so that I can get the num_views_per_telecast for the episodes in the bottom query. Not quite sure how I would inner join these though so I could keep the results from the first set of queries.

How the tables are connected are below:

[image]

How would I combine these???

Comment: Why not just paste the where clause from the second query into the first, before the order by (and put the rest of the telecast columns in the select)? `SELECT DISTINCT *` is probably a mistake because you've selected the primary key column as well (the DISTINCT is redundant)

Answer (score 2):

At a guess:

```sql
SELECT 
  t.*,
  ti.num_views_per_telecast
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      ti.telecast_id,
      ti.network_id,
      count(*) as num_views_per_telecast
    FROM
      tunein AS ti
      INNER JOIN
      affiliates AS a
      ON
        ti.network_id = a.network_id
      WHERE
        ti.dvr_time_shift = 'L+SD' and 
        a.network_name = 'ABC'
      group by
        ti.telecast_id,
        ti.network_id
  )ti
  inner join telecast AS t
  On 
    t.telecast_id = ti.telecast_id

  --from query2
  where 
    t.episode_name = 'friday night dinner'
    and t.series_name = 'A Million Little Things'
    and t.date(program_start_local) = '2018-10-17'


  ORDER BY ti.num_views_per_telecast DESC
```

For reasons given in the comment, the `DISTINCT` is redundant so you seem to want all rows from telecast that match some criteria. Given that your first query contains telecast but without any criteria and you only select one column from it, merging the two is a case of boosting the number of columns selected to (all from telecast) plus anything else, and adding the where clause from query 2 to restrict the rows in query 1

Comment: Even better turn `WHERE` clauses to `ON` clauses: `ON t.telecast_id = ti.telecast_id AND t.episode_name = 'friday night dinner' ...`